# How can I access the address book in Xamarin.forms (for android and iOS)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms, addressbook

I'm a noob who have struggling with this for hours. Tried a lot of stuff (including trying to use AppCompact and ContactsPlugin (maybe those would work, but I just wasn't able to achieve it)) and nothing.

If you have a simple solution, it would be ideal.

Comment: use the Contacts plugin.  If you have problems with it, describe the specific problem instead of saying "didn't work"

Comment: I donwloaded the zip and extracted it, but there weren't clear steps to add it to my solution/project. Do you have a fools proof guide that i could use?

Comment: If you have any problem when you tried to achieve this function, you can post the detalis about your question.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/contacts-app-email-sms-phone-navigation-with-xamarin-essentials/

Comment: (Thanks, Jessie, have a good week :P)

Jason, I read the blog and that isn't what I want. I don't want to create contacts, I want to access the contacts on the phone :/

Comment: Have you check this link: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ContactsPlugin ?

Comment: Yes, but wasn't able to make it work :(

Comment: Look, I added it again, but I just the need to code to make it work (told you, I'm a noob). I want to see the contacts listed, that's all, do you know how to do it?

Comment: We can't get  Nuget `Xam.Plugin.Contacts` anymore.But we can try to achieve this function by using `DependencyServices` .For more details: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-mvvm-how-to-fetch-mobile-contacts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer turned out to be disappointing: at this moment, there's no simple way and it's better to just work natively on each version (in any case, there seems to be a way to add native code to your Xamarin project, but it's useless if you already write the most important things separately)